# DocuSign API - Date Tab Input Format

Tags: docusignapi

I'm adding some Date Tabs to my envelope and would like the user to be able to either select from the calendar or enter the date manually, but always have it appear in DD/MM/YYYY format. Here's the code for the Date tab:

```
"dateTabs" : 
[
    {
        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
        "anchorString" : "/UserDate/",
        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
        "documentId" : "1",
        "height" : "",
        "locked" : "false",
        "name" : "Date Signed",
        "pageNumber" : "1",
        "required" : "true",
        "tabLabel" : "Data Signed",
        "value" : "",
        "width" : ""
    }
],
```

When the user selects a Date (e.g. 25 Dec 2022) it is stored in MM/DD/YYYY format on the DocuSign remote signing page:

[image]

If they try and enter a DD/MM/YYYY date they get this error message:

[image]

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/create/#schema__enveloperecipienttabs_datetabs) for Date Tabs it states that `The tooltip for this tab recommends entering the date as MM/DD/YYYY, but this is not enforced. The format entered by the signer is retained`. How do I allow users to enter DD/MM/YYYY dates here then and have this retained?

Comment: Just a long shot but in the UI you can default a format @ https://support.tiltorigin.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007522218-DocuSign-Setting-the-date-and-time-format#:~:text=Along%20with%20the%20insertion%20of,DD%2FMM%2FYYYY). it's worth looking at

Comment: @IlanP I believe that only applies to Date Signed tabs not Date tabs. We already have the Date Signed defaulting to DD/MM/YYYY and would like to set the Date tabs the same.

Comment: I was reading a bit further, another shot would be to make sure the settings for the date format are in place for the user you are authenticating as when sending the envelopes via the API; you are correct when their docs says this validation isn't enforced as well - if you're using a service account you made to generate the envelopes, I'd give a try to editing the settings for that account (date format); again worth a try. Also see - https://support.databuzz.com.au/article/580-changing-the-format-of-the-date-signed-field (maybe we can get lucky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a RegEx pattern for validation like this:

```
"dateTabs" : 
[
    {
        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
        "anchorString" : "/UserDate/",
        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
        "documentId" : "1",
        "height" : "",
        "locked" : "false",
        "name" : "Date Signed",
        "pageNumber" : "1",
        "required" : "true",
        "tabLabel" : "Data Signed",
        "value" : "",
        "width" : "",
        "validationPattern":"^(|by DocuSign)((|0)[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/((|0)[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}$",
        "validationMessage":""
    }
],
```